# OC 2.0 Fedex shipping method not working

Tags: opencart2.x, fedex

We tried to Fedex shipping method in our opencart website.
It Display the "Error" text.

> ERRORERRORcrs691The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.
>   The PurposeOfShipmentType is null, empty or invalid.crs1000

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v13">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<RateRequest>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>XXXXX</Key>
      <Password>XXXXX</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </WebAuthenticationDetail>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>XXXXX</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>XXXXX</MeterNumber>
  </ClientDetail>
  <TransactionDetail>
    <CustomerTransactionId>MY-RATE-REQUEST</CustomerTransactionId>
  </TransactionDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
    <Major>13</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ReturnTransitAndCommit>
  <RequestedShipment>
    <ShipTimestamp>2012-10-09T14:28:07.9489435+05:30</ShipTimestamp>
                <DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>   

                <PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
    <Shipper>
      <Address>
        <StreetLines>Sardarnagar Main Road, Rajkot</StreetLines>
        <City>Rajkot</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>GJ</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>360001</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <Recipient>
      <Address>
        <StreetLines>Radhekrishna App. Main Road , Rajkot</StreetLines>
        <City>Bhuj</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>GJ</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>370001</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Recipient>
    <ShippingChargesPayment>
    <PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>      
      <Payor>
        <ResponsibleParty>
          <AccountNumber>XXXXX</AccountNumber>
        </ResponsibleParty>
      </Payor>
    </ShippingChargesPayment>
    <CustomsClearanceDetail>
      <DutiesPayment>
        <PaymentType>RECIPIENT</PaymentType>
      </DutiesPayment>
      <DocumentContent>NON_DOCUMENTS</DocumentContent>
      <CustomsValue>
        <Currency>INR</Currency>
        <Amount>299.000000</Amount>
      </CustomsValue>
      <CommercialInvoice>
        <Purpose>NOT_SOLD</Purpose>
      </CommercialInvoice>
    </CustomsClearanceDetail>
    <RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</RateRequestTypes>
    <RateRequestTypes>LIST</RateRequestTypes>
    <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
    <RequestedPackageLineItems>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
      <Weight>
        <Units>KG</Units>
        <Value>1</Value>
      </Weight>
    </RequestedPackageLineItems>
  </RequestedShipment>
</RateRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: How i can call this in my c# code, means i want use this service, how i can implement